# normalization 1NF or 3NF

Tags: normalization, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

though after reading many articles online and I know this question have been asked quite a number of time. I'm still having problem identifying if a relation table is in 1NF, 2NF or 3NF

I've found an example as below

Students are involved in many project, and each project may have
many employee working on it. The number of hours each Students
works on a project, and the start date on which the students starts
working on the project are saved in the following relational table.

```
StudProject (StudNum, ProjNum, HoursWork,
DateStartWorkOnProj)
```

I've tried breaking them into the following on my own which i'm not sure if i'm right

```
StudNum, ProjNum  --> HoursWork, DateStartWorkOnProj
         StudNum  --> ProNum
         ProNum   --> HoursWork, DateStartWorkOnProj
```

so it actually has a transitive dependency so in this case it should be under 2NF? or should it be 3NF since the hourswork and datestartworkonproj actually depends on StudNum and ProjNum..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have only these data for every project, i think this table is good.

`StudProject (StudNum, ProjNum, HoursWork,
DateStartWorkOnProj)`

but if you want  to store more information about project and work time, this table must be extended:

`StudProject (StudNum, ProjNum)`

`projectWork (StudNum, ProjNum, workTime, startDateTime, endDateTime)`

in the projectWork table, each record show a work day of student and difference of start, ned saved in workTime. sum(workTime) for each student in a project shows a total work of him.

Comment: can i have another que for you.. 

A,B -> C
  C -> A

is this considered as transitively dependent?

Comment: Suppose all three of the following conditions hold:   
1. A → B   
2. It is not the case that B → A   
3. B → C   
Then the functional dependency A → C (which follows from 1 and 3 by the axiom of transitivity) is a transitive dependency.